# RNA integrity and RNA fragmentation

Tags: rna

After RNA isolation and before following experiments, I know that RNA quality so called RNA integrity is so important. So why there is a RNA fragmentation kit? Do we need RNA intact or fragmented? (RNA will be used for biotinylation and RT-qPCR afterwards)

Answer (score 1):

This [paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2822713/) uses a similar technique to you by purifying total RNA, synthesis of double-stranded cDNA containing a T7 promoter sequence, cDNA purification, in vitro transcription in the presence of biotin-labeled ribonucleotides and this transcription is possible with T7 RNA polymerase since the cDNA contains the T7 promoter region, and finally fractionation of RNA. This then allows target biotin-labeled RNA for short (~ 25 nucleotides) oligonucleotide arrays. The T7 polymerase performs a linear amplification, and the in vitro RNA obtained reflects the abundance of each transcript in the initial RNA.

Hence I assume you follow a similar protocol although I'm not sure why you do RT-qPCR on the fragmented RNA since that is unlikely to work if you are doing it using primers for specific regions as everything is fragmented. So I think you do a RT-qPCR before the fragmentation to test the expression levels of certain (known) genes (to see if you are getting the expected results) before you go ahead with fragmentation and look at the global RNA expression. If my assumptions are wrong, then it would be great if you added further details of your experimental protocols with the different steps and the exact orders of the steps followed and the results assessed and the experiments performed so that I can modify my response.